# numpy apply a function over an array of matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say I have an array of 2D matrices (i.e. a 3D array)

```
a = np.random.rand(10,2,2)
```

Now I want to apply a function over that 10 `2x2` matrices. e.g.

```
def test(i):
    return i.shape
b  = np.array([test(i) for i in a])
```

So, `b` will be a array of 10 tuples `(2,2)`. Now is there any numpy way to do this without the explicit looping? I tried `apply_along_axis` but that only apply the function only over a single axis.

Comment: Can you explain a little about what is exactly your function? Mostly, a function can be implemented to work on a matrix in vectorized form.

Comment: you can also have look at [`apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) and [`apply_over_axes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html).

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is not a speed tool.  Look at its code.

Comment: Is your function written in Python, and does it have to be called once for each submatrix?  Then there isn't much you can do the speed things up.  Each of those calls takes time, and unless the function is trival, those calls will dominate the total time.  `numpy` itself does not have any mechanism for 'compiling' your own Python code.

Comment: Given that numpy does not support ragged arrays, I'd say that your contrived example is unfortunately chosen

Comment: Show us some code which actually does something useful that we can try to optimize.  Optimizing pointless code is pointless.

Comment: You can try [np.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). This would eliminate external looping, although ```vectorize``` is basically a for loop internally so you won't get any optimization benefits from it.